# Detect multiple tabs opening... and close the newest tabs! (via BroadcastChannel API)

Tags: javascript, html, callback, tabs, message

I've put this function on load so I can detect a new tab being opened:

```
function checkNewTabs() {
  const channel = new BroadcastChannel('tab');
  channel.postMessage('newTab');
  channel.addEventListener('message', (msg) => {
    if (msg.data === 'newTab') {
      alert('Please don't open more than one tab at a time!');
      //window.open('', '_self', '').close();
    }
  });
}
```

I want to be able to send a message back to the new tab like this:

```
channel.postMessage('callbackNewTab');
channel.addEventListener('message', (msgBack) => {
  if (msgBack.data === 'callbackNewTab') {
    alert('This tab will be closed!');
    window.open('', '_self', '').close();
  }
});
```

In order to close the new tab...

I can do it for the old tab but what I really need is for it to close the new tab!

Can anyone help me out please? tks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for 2 tabs. For more tabs need some master / slave index.

```
const EVENT_NEW_TAB = "newTabOpened";
const EVENT_CLOSE_TAB = "needCloseThisTab";

const CHANNEL_NAME = "tab";

const channel = new BroadcastChannel(CHANNEL_NAME);
channel.onmessage = (event) =>
{
    let data = event.data;

    switch (data)
    {
        case EVENT_NEW_TAB:
            onNewTabOpened();
            break;
        case EVENT_CLOSE_TAB:
            onNeedCloseThisTab();
            break;
    }
}

function onNewTabOpened()
{
    channel.postMessage(EVENT_CLOSE_TAB);  // Send message to second tab
}

function onNeedCloseThisTab()
{
    alert('This tab will be closed!');

    window.open("about:blank", "_self").close(); // Need some hack
}

function onPageLoad()
{
    channel.postMessage(EVENT_NEW_TAB); // Send message to first tab
}

window.onload = () =>
{
    onPageLoad();
};
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post